# opening a .pdf document in chrome using python

Tags: python, google-chrome, pdf

I am making a program, where one part of it it to open a .pdf document in chrome. the program is made in python 3.5.x. the program returns no errors when run but it doesn't open any new tabs or windows. with the .pdf. I am using the webbrowser module.

```
chrome_path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe %s'
    webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open_new('http://google.com')
    #'file:///I:/TESTFOLDER/SDDsyllabus.pdf'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *Subprocess* to do that:

```
import subprocess
chrome_path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe #Notice how I'm using the backslash '\' not the normals slash '/'/
p = subprocess.Popen([chrome_path, "!%!PUT PATH TO PDF FILE HERE!%!"]) #This uses 'Subprocess' to open the file
returncode = p.wait() #This waits for the process to close
```

What it does is open a file with a process, basically it opens that file with(In this case) *Chrome*.

*Note: This will open a new window not a new tab.*

Hope this helps :-)

If you need any more help just ask.

*~Coolq*